# How do I limit the number of jobs in Google Bigquery

Tags: javascript, sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

In order to have a better overview of what happens in our CRM (ActiveCampaign) and to create our own reports, I now post all changes to a BigQuery database using webhooks and a Google Apps Script.

This works very well, however I found out there is a limit of 1000 load jobs, and every change in the CRM creates at least one, sometimes more load jobs. This limit cannot be increased in any way. So I am looking for a way to batch the entries and load them every 10 minutes.

I don't know however how to create that in an Apps script that is triggered by a webhook and I cannot find it anywhere online. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I think Cron jobs, Apache Airflow, Oozie, and Web Services in App Engine as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584097/cron-bigquery-jobs) are some good options to limit the number of BigQuery jobs.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a time delay to your event handling by serializing the events into a data storage device (like Google Sheets) in the initial webhook, and then using a time-based trigger to read saved events and send them to BigQuery.

```
function doPost(e) {
  var hdd = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id");
  /* Pick the sheet to log to based on parameters of the event */
  var params = e.parameters, sector = "";
  if(...) {
    sector = "some sheet name";
  } else if(...) {
    sector = "some other sheet name"
  }
  ... // Do other stuff with event that needs immediate handling.
  // Serialize for batch processing later.
  hdd.getSheetByName(sector).appendRow([JSON.stringify(e)]);
}
// Fire events in bulk. Create a time based trigger to call this function every so often.
function refireEvents() {
  var sectors = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id").getSheets();
  for(var i = 0; i < sectors.length; ++i) {
    var events = sectors[i].getDataRange().getValues();
    var sheetName = sectors[i].getName();
    for(var r = 0; r < events.length; ++r) {
      var event = JSON.parse(events[r][0]); // Assuming only single column of data
      /* Do stuff with the event response that was originally done in the webhook */
    }
    // Remove handled events.
    sectors[i].clearContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: I implemented it, and after some tweaking it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use you Google Apps Script to create a web service (web app) that will receive the request and then perform your batch operation.

Simply handle either the `doGet()` or `doPost()` method in your script, then when the script is published the function corresponding method will be invoked whenever a `GET` or `POST` request is made to the script's URL.

See the Web Apps guide: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web